# Insert Date into Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I want to insert a datetime into a date field in oracle. I have up until now used sysdate, which works perfectly, however I need to use the same timestamp for something else.

Does anyone know how I can create a datetime variable that is compatible with oracle's date field? Everything I try causes errors.

I have tried variations along the lines of this:

```
Dim timestamp As DateTime = CDate(Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))

.......more code....

insertBuilder.Append("date = to_date(" & timestamp & ")")
```

Comment: Why take a date, convert to String and then _back_ to date?  That is just unnecessary work.  If you use a parameterized query, you won't have to go through that trouble!

Comment: I get what you are saying. The code above is lousy but being new to VB I don't yet know much better. All i want to do is create a datetime / timestamp as a variable and insert it into the Oracle Date field.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parameterised query is a good start because you can pass a native .Net DateTime object into Enterprise Library (for example) and specify that it is of `DbType.DateTime` and let EL worry about it. However if you cannot do that because you aren't using EL or something similar and are stuck with using SQL strings as posted in your question then you need to be aware of how Oracle treats dates internally, particularly with regards to format.

Using SQL Developer or SQLPlus, execute the following:

```
Select To_Char(sysdate) from Dual;
```

The format which is displayed is the format which your Oracle instance expects dates to be in if you use To_Date and which Oracle will use in To_Char. If you deviate from that format in either call then you will get problems. However, regardless of the default format being used you can override it by specifying it in the call:

```
Select To_Char(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') from Dual;
Select To_Date('2013/02/26 05:03:27', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS') from Dual;
```

You can set the default you want Oracle to use implicitly by setting the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS';
```

Note that the previous statement only alters the default **for the session in which it is executed**. We use a custom format in our Oracle systems and to ensure that we get it on all sessions we use an after logon trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER NLS_Parameters_OnLogon  AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA BEGIN    

-- This makes the database case insensitive for sorting and searching and sets the default date format for TO_CHAR and TO_DATE    

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC';   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI';  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=''YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'''; 
End;
```

It is possible to change the default date format for the whole Oracle server by editing some of the Oracle config files but since we have to deploy to client servers over which we have no control we use this method instead.

[This article](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html) covers the same sort of ground I just have with a little more in the way of examples.

Comment: WOW. That pretty much covers all of it. Thanks very much Steve

Comment: No problem - I remember the pain I went through the other way round: I knew the .Net side but had never used Oracle. It is well worth learning to use parameterised queries though as Steven Doggart says. They can make life easier as well as helping prevent SQL injection amongst other things. Lots of frameworks can help with that - we use EL5/EntlibContrib with ODP and Instant Client. Bit of a hassle to get that stack working at first but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

First, you seem to be confused about the difference between a `DateTime` object and the formatted `String` representation of that `DateTime` object.  `Now`, or even better, `DateTime.Now` is already a `DateTime` object, so it makes no sense to format it as a string and then parse the string to get it back into a `DateTime` value again.  So, you can simply do this to accomplish the same thing:

```
Dim timestamp As Date = Date.Now
```

Note that in VB.NET, `Date` is a keyword that is short for `DateTime`, just as `Integer` is "short" for `Int32`.

Second, you should not be appending `DateTime` values directly into the SQL command string.  You should be using a parameterized query.  When you append the `DateTime` value to the SQL string, you must make sure it is formatted properly (by calling `timestamp.ToString(...)`).  Unfortunately, however, which format is proper will depend entirely on the culture settings of the server.  So, it is far better to use a DB parameter, set the parameter value equal to the actual `DateTime` object, and then let the DB provider do the conversion for you.

Comment: I guess that's what I get for not reading the manual haha. Cheers for that!