# Insert a TimeStamp into a Stored Procedure in VB/Oracle

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Stored Procedure which reads in a TimeStamp.
In my program I have a DatePicker and a TimePicker which I'm then converting to a String, in the same format as the TimeStamp, ie. "timestamp'2009-09-09 09:30:25 CET'"

However, I get the following error when trying to run the procedure.
[image]

Here is the VB code (the first half is basically converting the DatePicker value into a string in the TimeStamp format):

```
Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("SYSTEM.ADDSCREENING", ChooseTable.Connect())

    Dim timeStamp As String = "timestamp'2009-12-31 09:30:25 CET'"
    Dim dateRaw As String = dtpStartDate.Text
    Dim dateArray() As String = Split(timeStamp, "-")
    Dim dateYear As String = dateArray(0)
    Dim dateMonth As String = dateArray(1)
    Dim dateArray2() As String = Split(dateArray(2), " ")
    Dim dateDay As String = dateArray2(0)

    Dim timeRaw As String = dtpStartTime.Text
    Dim timeFinal As String = timeRaw + ":00 GMT"

    Dim timeStampFinal As String = dateYear + "-" + dateMonth + "-" + dateDay + " " + timeFinal + "'"

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SCREENID", Val(cboScreen.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FILMID", Val(cboFilm.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@STARTTIME", timeStampFinal)

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record Added")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    RefreshDB()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094732/insert-date-into-oracle

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in the database?  Is it DateTime?  Is it Varchar?

Comment: The format in the table is "TIMESTAMP(6)"